# nuget pack command results the error Value cannot be null or an empty string. Parameter name: value

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to create my first nuget package by following [this guide](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package). I've generated a nuspec file and a MSBUILD targets file within a `build` subdirectory and have both included in the build output of a csrpoj. I now run `nuget pack` on my nuspec file as suggested within my `bin` directory and I get the following error.

```
> nuget pack MyPackage.nuspec
Value cannot be null or an empty string.
Parameter name: value
```

The error seems clear but the value that cannot be null is not. Here is an example of my current nuspec file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>source version tfs git</tags>

    <packageTypes>
      <packageType type="Dependency" />
    </packageTypes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <!-- Include everything in \build -->
    <file src="build\**"
          target="build" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 4):

Running nuget pack instead on my project file resulted in more useful information

```
The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'packageTypes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'references, contentFiles, dependencies, developmentDependency, frameworkAssemblies, summary, language' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'.
```

After adding the following namespace no changes.

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
```

Removing the packageTypes elemtn resulted in further progress.

```
Authors is required.
Description is required.
```

Filled in Authors and Description which left me only with a warning.

```
WARNING: 1 issue(s) found with package 'SourceVersion'.

Issue: Remove sample nuspec values.
Description: The value "Summary of changes made in this release of the package." for ReleaseNotes is a sample value and should be removed.
Solution: Replace with an appropriate value or remove and it and rebuild your package.
```

Filled in the ReleaseNotes content which then allowed the package to be created without error.

NOTE: Running nuget pack directly on the nuspec file still gives me the same error after these changes from above. But running `nuget pack MyPackage.csproj` is now working fine for me which is good enough for me at the moment.

Comment: Nothing that I can from above @MichaelPuckettII. I haven't attempted publishing anything more recently than about mid-spring 2017 and I followed the same steps as above since I have them scripted as part of the build processes now.

Comment: I had the same issue. When your .nuspec file contains variables (such as $id$) you have to point nuget.exe at the .csproj instead. Otherwise nuget doesn't know where to pull the variables from.